# How to show all products which not included in another table. by STRING_AGG

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-agg

I am currently working on part of a project which is about products and variants.

Product Table

```
productID   productName
-------------------------
1           Perfume X
2           Perfume Y
```

Variants Table

```
variantID   variantName productID
1           color       1
2           volume      1
```

VariantValue Table

```
variantValueID  variantValue    variantID
1               Red             1
2               Blue            1
3               Green           1
4               100ML           2
5               50ML            2
```

ProductVariant Table

```
productVariantID    productID   sku price
1                   1           111 50.00
2                   1           222 30.00
4                   1           333 15.00
5                   2           444 10.95
```

ProductDetail Table

```
ProductDetailID productVariantID    variantValueID
1               1                   1
2               1                   4
3               2                   1
4               2                   5
5               4                   2
6               4                   5
```

[relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2sai.png)

and when I call this query ..

```
SELECT  p.productName + ' ' + STRING_AGG(vv.variantValue,' ') product,pv.price
FROM
    product p
    JOIN ProductVariant pv ON pv.productID = p.productID
    JOIN ProductDetail pd ON pv.productVariantID = pd.productVariantID
    join VariantValue vv ON pd.variantValueID = vv.variantValueID
GROUP BY pd.productVariantID, p.productName,pv.price
```

I get the following result ..

```
product             price
Perfume X Red 100ML 50.00
Perfume X Red 50ML  30.00
Perfume X Blue 50ML 15.00
```

So far so good, it shows all products with the prices but when I insert a new product without variants (*simple product*) it does not appeared. In my case Perfume Y does not have any variants.

I tried using right and full join but in vain. How I show all products including those product that have no variants.

Comment: What is string aggregate has to do with this question?

Comment: You sample query includes inner joins. Naturally if any relation records are missing in any one of the tables the join will ignore this record. See: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp to find out how joins work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a `left join`:

```
SELECT p.productName + COALESCE(' ' + STRING_AGG(vv.variantValue,' '), '') as product,
       pv.price
FROM product p LEFT JOIN
     ProductVariant pv
     ON pv.productID = p.productID LEFT JOIN
     ProductDetail pd
     ON pv.productVariantID = pd.productVariantID LEFT JOIN
     VariantValue vv
     ON pd.variantValueID = vv.variantValueID
GROUP BY p.productName, pv.price
```

Comment: thank you on reply.. it shows the row but the name of the product is NULL.

Comment: @طلالالعنزي . . . You need `COALESCE()` for that part.